# How to get count of invalid data during parse

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

We are using spark to parse a big csv file, which may contain invalid data. 
We want to save valid data into the data store, and also return how many valid data we imported and how many invalid data.

I am wondering how we can do this in spark, what's the standard approach when reading data?

My current approach uses `Accumulator`, but it's not accurate due to how `Accumulator` works in spark.

```
// we define case class CSVInputData: all fields are defined as string
val csvInput = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv(csvFile).as[CSVInputData]

val newDS = csvInput
  .flatMap { row =>
    Try {
      val data = new DomainData()
      data.setScore(row.score.trim.toDouble)
      data.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
      data.setDate(Util.parseDate(row.eventTime.trim))
      data.setUpdateDate(new Date())
      data
    } match {
      case Success(map) => Seq(map)
      case _ => {
        errorAcc.add(1)
        Seq()
      }
    }
}
```

I tried to use `Either`, but it failed with the exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: no Java class corresponding to Product with Serializable with scala.util.Either[xx.CSVInputData,xx.DomainData] found

**Update**

I think Either doesn't work with spark 2.0 dataset api:

```
      spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("any.csv").map { row => 
      try {
        Right("")
      } catch {  case e: Throwable => Left(""); }
      }
```

If we change to use sc(rdd api), it works:

```
      sc.parallelize('a' to 'z').map { row => 
      try {
        Right("")
      } catch {  case e: Throwable => Left(""); }
      }.collect()
```

In current latest scala http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.x/index.html#scala.util.Either: Either doesn't implements Serializable trait

```
sealed abstract class Either[+A, +B] extends AnyRef
```

In future 2.12 http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/util/Either.html, it does:

```
sealed abstract class Either[+A, +B] extends Product with Serializable
```

**Updated 2 with workaround**

More info at [Spark ETL: Using Either to handle invalid data](http://lifelongprogrammer.blogspot.com/2016/10/spark-etl-using-either-to-handle.html)

As spark dataset doesn't work with Either, so the workaround is to call ds.rdd, then use try-left-right to capture both valid and invalid data.

```
   spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("/Users/yyuan/jyuan/1.csv").rdd.map ( { row => 
   try {
     Right("")
   } catch {  case e: Throwable => Left(""); }
   }).collect()
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using an [Either](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/Either.html)

```
val counts = csvInput
      .map { row =>
        try {
          val data = new DomainData()
          data.setScore(row.score.trim.toDouble)
          data.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
          data.setDate(Util.parseDate(row.eventTime.trim))
          data.setUpdateDate(new Date())
          Right(data)
        } catch {
          case e: Throwable => Left(row)
        }
      }
      val failedCount = counts.map(_.left).filter(_.e.isLeft).count()
      val successCount = counts.map(_.right).filter(_.e.isRight).count()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I did try to use either, but it throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: no Java class corresponding to Product with Serializable with scala.util.Either[xx.CSVInputData,xx.DomainData] found

Comment: You'll probably need to use Kyro serialisation:

import spark.implicits._
implicit val domainDataEncoder = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[DomainData]

Comment: I think the old RDD related api works with Either but spark 2.0 dataset api  doesn't work with Either. Please check my update in the origin question. Thanks

Comment: Found the workaround with the dataset api issue - just call dataset.rdd, then use try-catch-left-right. It works. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: didn't you have performance penalisation transforming to RDD? In theory is slower.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Spark DDQ - this has most of the data quality rules that you will need. You can even extend and customize it.

Link: https://github.com/FRosner/drunken-data-quality